# Solving differential equation problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

As a result of an unforgivable miss, the solution to an assignment will be discovered by a student at 00.00 night to November 14. This information spreads among the students and two days later half of the students know the solution.
According to one model, the spread rate at time t (in hours after discovery) is proportional to the product of three factors

(1) the number of students who know the solution at time t, [i.e. how many that
can disseminate information]

(2) the number of students who do not know the solution at time t [i.e. How many
who can receive the information] and

(3) 1 - sin (πt / 12) [students are at least active at 06 in the morning].

We ignore that the number of students is an integer and describes the process of a derivative function f (t) which describes the number of students who know the solution at time t (in hours). There are A> 1 students.

(a) Set up the initial value problem that describes the situation.

(b) Solve the initial value problem.

(c) The missing is detected after four days. How many students know the solution at this time?

What I have done:

a) $f'(t)=f(t)*(A-f(t))*(1-sin(\frac{\pi*t}{12})$

b) Here I'm struggling, because I don't know where to start. What is the best method?

Answer (score 2):

Note that you can separate the factors containing $t$ and the ones containing $f(t)$. Denoting $f(t)$ by $y$, we have

$$ \frac{dy}{dt} = y \cdot (A - y) \cdot (1 - \sin(\frac{\pi \cdot t}{12}))$$

$$\iff$$

$$ \frac{dy}{y \cdot (A - y)} =  dt \cdot (1 - \sin(\frac{\pi \cdot t}{12}))$$

at which point you have to integrate both sides. (Calculate the constant using the initial values described in the problem)

Comment: Then you will have to decompose the LHS into $B(1/y+1/(A-y))$ for a certain $B$...

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I understand now. But one thing. I forgot to write k in my equation, as one normally do. Isn't that essential?

Comment: What do you mean by $k$?

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof When you for example write an differential equation knowing that the rate of increase is proportional to the function, you write $\frac{dy}{dx}=k*y$. So shouldn't I write $\frac{dy}{dt} = y \cdot (A - y) \cdot (1 - \sin(\frac{\pi \cdot t}{12}))*k$ ????

Comment: Ah, good point. Yes, you should include a $k$. This shouldn't make the math any harder really.

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof Thank you so much! Really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Okay, so I have almost solved the equation but I'm struggling with finding a solution for y. I got this
$\frac{1}{A}$*$ln(y)$-$\frac{1}{A}*ln(A-y)$=$k*(x+frac\{12}{pi}*cos(\frac{pi}{12})$

Comment: Sorry, I mean:$\frac{1}{A}*ln(y)-\frac{1}{A}*ln(A-y)=k*(x+\frac{12}{pi}*cos(\frac{pi}{12}*x)$

Comment: Note that you can use \pi in mathmode to get the pi-symbol. Replace $x$ with $t$; use the rule for sum (/difference) of two logarithms on the left hand-side and then exponentiate.